# Luz fria es cálida y luz caliente es fría

Tags: adjetivos

De la [rae (cálido)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6ndKu1I%7C6ndNVxF):

> 3. Dicho de una gama de colores: Que va desde el amarillo al rojo pasando por el naranja.

De [Wikipedia (Temperatura de color)](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Temperatura_de_color&oldid=104090444):

> [image: Color de un cuerpo negro entre 800 y 12 200 K.]
>   [(Las cifras están en Kelvin)]

¿Se puede decir que la luz fría es cálida (y viceversa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pregunta es buena, pero tiene más que ver con ciencia que con el español, puesto que esto ocurre en todos los idiomas.

Los adjetivos `cálida` y `fría` hacen referencia a la percepción subjetiva que tenemos los humanos (y los bichos, ¿por qué no...?) del color.

Sin embargo, la `temperatura de color` (concepto científicamente riguroso) es la temperatura que se ha de aplicar a un sistema físico ideal y extremadamente importante (conocido como "Cuerpo Negro") para obtener ese color.

Un objeto real que existe y se parece bastante es el filamento de una bombilla, o un metal en una fragua. Cuando se calienta, se pone al rojo vivo (incandescente), de color rojizo. Si se calienta mucho más se va poniendo anaranjado e incluso llega al blanco ("al blanco vivo", menos conocida expresión, pero usada). No se suelen alcanzar temperaturas suficientes para verlos azulados. Sin embargo en el espacio, las estrellas blancas y azules están más calientes que las rojas.

De modo que en cierto modo tienes razón, pero son dos conceptos distintos. Una cosa es la temperatura real de un Cuerpo Negro ideal (o de lo más parecido que tenemos por casa en las bombillas viejas, que se llama Cuerpo Gris), que es una magnitud muy clara. Otra cosa distinta es qué sensación nos produzca a los humanos, eso es subjetivo, y lo llamamos "cálido" o "frío".

¿Y a qué se debe esta "discrepancia tan abismal"? Pues la respuesta es evolutiva: a ningún ser vivo le interesa percibir el azul como más caliente que el rojo, porque ningún sistema en la Tierra alcanza una temperatura tan bestia como para que se vea azul.

Muy por el contrario, resulta que el fuego quema y es naranja, y la nieve es fría y blanca. Igualmente el agua que encontramos en la naturaleza y el hielo son transparentes pero solemos encontrarlos azulados por distintos motivos. Evolutivamente interesa asociar el rojo y el naranja (color del fuego) con caliente, y los otros como fríos.

Comment: hablar de colores calidos y frios es algo mas artistico que cientifico, los colores calidos son aquellos que nos recuerdan superficies o sensaciones calidas, como lo son los colores opacos que nos recuerdan a la madera, o el fuego, mientras que los colores frios son los que nos recuerdan superficies frias y lisas, como los colores brillantes.

Comment: ahora hablar de luz calida y luz fria es cientifico, 
la luz calida es la que es emitida por un bulbo, o algun objeto incandesente, como el fuego o un bulbo, mintras que la luz fria es aquella que es emitida por exitacion electrica, como los Leds o las luces de neon